# Chromatic number of transposition graph of permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $S_n$ be the set of all bijections (permutations) $\pi:[n]\to [n]$. For any set $X$ let  $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y\in X\big\}$. We let $\pi,\psi\in S_n$ be connected by an edge if "they are one transposition away from each other", or more formally, set $$E_n = \big\{\{\pi,\psi\}\in [S_n]^2:\exists a<b\in[n]:\big(\psi = (a\;\;b)\circ\pi\big) \text{ or } \big(\psi = \pi\circ(a\;\; b)\big)\big\}.$$

Given any positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$, what is $\chi(S_n, E_n)$?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but isn't $\chi(S_n,E_n)$ always $2$? Just color the permutations by their sign.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Thanks for your comment - I believe you are right! Can you put this down as a short answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\geq 2$, we have
$$\chi(S_n, E_n) = 2.$$
It is at most $2$, since we can color permutations by their signs. It is obviously at least $2$.